# Logical "OR" of two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to make logical "OR" of two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'call_id':'aa','486':0,'487':1}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'call_id':'aa','503':1,'487':1}])    
df1 = df1.set_index('call_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('call_id')   
df3 = df1 | df2
```

and result is:

```
         486  487  503
call_id               
aa       NaN    1  NaN
```

But wished result is :

```
         486  487  503
call_id               
aa       0    1    1
```

How i can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for all possible columns and pass to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same columns names in both DataFrames:

```
cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)
df3 = df1.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0) | df2.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0) 

print (df3)
         486  487  503
call_id               
aa         0    1    1
```

Out of box solution with [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), but then need convert greater like `1` to `1`:

```
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).gt(1).astype(int)
#alternative
#df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).clip(upper=1).astype(int)

print (df3)
         486  487  503
call_id               
aa         0    1    1
```